# gazebo freezes when saving new world

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I have installed Gazebo 9 with ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. I keep getting the following problem:

- Start Gazebo
- Add some objects to the world
- File -> Save As...
- The program freezes and the saving window does not show up

It is possible to Alt+F4 to return to the world editor but nothing saves.
Help me if anyone knows about that

Comment: gazebo 11 is having this same issue on ubuntu 20. it has something to do with the save window not showing. If you Ctrl+Alt+Down, and then back, to change workspaces, it can get the save dialog to show up, but, you still can't interact with it.

Comment: this [issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2357) has been tracked for about a year with no attention yet. I'm not sure why? The inability to save worlds seems like a major show stopper.

Comment: I have passed my Final Year Project anyhow but still not solved this problem

Comment: how have you gotten around this issue? I've actually seen old tickets showing it goes back about 12 years, where you can't save worlds on Linux (not to mention tonsa other bugs).  I think I'll give up Gazebo and use PyBullet directly.

Comment: World on gazebo works on some Pc's so a friend of mine helped me to sketch a world and save it on his computer.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and using Gazebo 9 installed with ros-melodic.
I had the same problem.
One of the ways to solve problem is to run gazebo with sudo.

https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/23755/save-as-wont-load-when-clicked/

Comment: This seems like to be not the nicest workaround. Is there no other solution? I mean, what does gazebo access where it benefits from the sudo rights?

Answer (score 2):

Looking for this issue I read in some where else that is a problem of image/windows configuration/postioning, it like the save windows is hided behind the gazebo screen. So, I try to minimize the gazebo window and maximize again, it works and the save window appears. The problem is that you must do this after each clcik (e.g. folder, type file name etc.) to “update the screen”.

Answer (score -2):

Can you run Gazebo from command line and get more details about the error? You can press tab and see all commands.